# Is it possible to integrate Stripe With Firebase and with iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments, zapier

I've been querying on Google on how to do this - iOS to Stripe. I got a project that uses an online database and I've been doing it solo (it's almost done) so I used Firebase. I was so lucky to find this BaaS and time passed, I only need to integrate a payment feature to this iOS app and I am done. I am not a web developer/backend dev and I only focus on iOS development, so the problem is that I can't start implementing a payment feature.

I didn't consider using Braintree, for I know that it requires a server, so I chose Stripe since it's much simpler, and little did I know that it also requires a server.

Here's what I did so far in my research:

1. I found a [tutorial on Raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe) - iOS to Strip using Python, but it doesn't teach how to setup the server and coding python itself.
2. I found this [StripeFire Node.js library](https://github.com/davidcaseria/StripeFire) on GitHub - but its last commit was 2 years ago, so I believe it's dead?
3. I read about using herokuapps to host my backend stuff for this project, so I began signing up on that site, and so far I can't use it because I'm still figuring out the whole process of hooking up to stripe from iOS.
4. I read about the Zapier to integrate FIREBASE + Stripe, it's not free, but I'm still considering it even though I got no idea yet how to use it for iOS.
5. Lastly, this is by far, the best tutorial I found - [APP CODE Tutorial - iOS to Web Server and To Stripe](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-stripe-payment-integration/) --- this is my last hope but I posted this question first before I proceed because I am using Firebase and I thought there might be easy ways to hookup Firebase to Sripe, and this tutorial doesn't use Firebase. This tutorial is really understandable and it's using PHP for the server side, I somehow have the knowledge in deploying PHP files to free hosting servers on the web ---- Do you think this way is okay?

So... the main purpose of this question is for me to know the best way and easy way for an iOS person who doesn't know much about server side stuff (I only know PHP and hosting files on some hosting sites) how to put a payment functionality to my app and at the same time the record of the payment/orders will be saved to Firebase.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but did you find a solution? I'm facing the same thing now and any help would be appreciated

Comment: hi @D.Greg, what step did you take? It's already December. :) I used PayPal. You can use PayPal server-less. iOS Client to PayPal directly. But right now, I'll be needing to step up myself because I really need a Stripe for my project. Thanks!

Comment: @user5156051 I'm using PayPal too - both senders, and receivers of payments need to eventually make PayPal accounts, right?

Answer (score 8):

You can implement entirely in Firebase without a server now that [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/features/functions) has launched. [There's a Stripe example up on Github.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe)

Comment: Doesn't this assume that you at least know JavaScript? Is there a way to do this in only iOS languages? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to an example project that uses realtime database for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. Looked for solutions in every forum. I started a post in Reddit and got a solution. I haven't implemented it.

firebase -> auth0 -> webtask -> stripe is one way to implement a true serverless

[Reddit post of true serverless payment implementation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/5sxtl3/is_it_possible_to_implement_a_payment_option_like/)

Also, @user5156051, I have a question on how did you implement PayPal serverless solution. I couldn't find the way. When I checked with the PayPal engineer's they mentioned you need to have your backend to perform the payment.

[Email conversation with PayPal engineer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz5uG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this organization. We are creating an iOS app that works on firebase and we make the app and the cloud functions (Firebase Functions/Google Cloud Functions) open tool. [IamGoogBad](https://github.com/IamGoodBad)