# How to set up firebase as server and execute stripe payment

Tags: swift, firebase, server, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I would like to use firebase as a server and send request to payment request to stripe. I have zero experience server side so I am looking for a simple way to achieve this. This post [Is it possible to integrate Stripe With Firebase and with iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386361/is-it-possible-to-integrate-stripe-with-firebase-and-with-ios) is close to what I want to achieve and it also list some interesting link. Does anyone know where I can find a good but simple tutorial to set up firebase as a server for stripe?

Comment: I did not find anything simple. Please note I have non knowledge re servers so what I find is pretty hard to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this with the following 2 steps

1. follow step 1, 2 and 3 of the the get started article (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). This has allowed me to install all the software which was needed (note I had several issue with firebase  tool install and node/npm but eventually I managed to install)
2. Follow this youtube guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsPGRIVOg0U). It is a nice video, simple to understand, on what to do to set up the function to request the execution of the payment.
3. create some logic in my swift app to save the stripe token in a realtime database as below

> func saveTokenInRealtimeDatabase(token: STPToken) {
>
> ```
>     let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "payments")     
>     ref.child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(["amount": valueToCharge,  "token": token.allResponseFields])
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You will find in the list of official Cloud Function samples, a sample on how to integrate Firestore and Stripe:

"Create Stripe customers and charge them on Cloud Firestore write", https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

Comment: I have seen this and it is all very hard to understand. Here is my current state: I have an iOS app and I am able to send credit card details to Stripe and get a token. Now I need to send a payment request to a server so that the server send back to stripe and eventually execute the payment. So I really need to just set up the server and I would like to use firebase...

Comment: "I need to send a payment request to a server" (which will communicate with the stripe API): the way you would do that with Firebase is by using Cloud Functions. Detailing here how you should set-up everything is way too broad... You should start with https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. It is probably a whole new world to get used to, but in any case if you want to set-up a back-end that will interact with the Stripe API you will need to get use to a "new world".